# Is putting a method call in a for loop considered bad practice?

Tags: c

Would the following be considered bad coding practice?

```
for (row = 0; row < 4; row++, printf("\n")) {
    for (col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: No. It's C.  Doesn't 'C' stand for cyrptic?  ;)

Comment: @KenThompson Ironically, the real meaning of the name 'C' is very cryptic...  'C' means "C comes after B in the alphabet, since the C language was based on the B language, which was a stripped down version of BCPL". Only C programmers name things in such far-fetched, cryptic terms! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is considered as bad practice. Rather than making a reply (of limited value) based on my own subjective opinions, I'll cite a widely-recognized authority:

MISRA-C:2004, rule 13.5:

> "The three statements of a for loop shall be concerned only with loop
>   control." /--/
>
> "Third expression:   Increment or decrement of the loop counter (i)."

MISRA-C also bans the use of the comma operator entirely: it is considered both superfluous and dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Let me respond with this question, which is better?

```
while(1) {}
```

or

```
for(;;) {}
```

Both compile to the same result and are effectively the same thing.  The same is true for your question when you add an arbitrary method call to the update portion of a for loop.  It compiles.  It works as expected.  The main difference is readability and preference.

I would venture that most programmers prefer putting method calls exclusively in the body of the for loops.  Not for any reason other than convention, so when someone else sees your for loop they don't have to spend as much time looking at the loop counters, etc.  You can be clever, sure, but I would recommend sticking to the established patterns so it's easier for your colleagues.  If you work with colleagues who prefer the obscure syntax, go for it until your heart's content!

Comment: *"If you work with colleagues who prefer the obscure syntax, go for it until your heart's content!"* Disagree. Your current colleagues are not the ones who will have to maintain your code longer after its expiration date. They may be whack jobs, but those of us who come along later are not guaranteed to inherit these traits.

Comment: This eternal loop style debate has been going on here and there. Some people believed while(1) was clearer and questioned the for(;;) style. I believe the consensus of that debate was that for(;;) is better, since it omits "condition is always true" compiler warnings. And that is the only difference between the two forms.

Comment: _"If you work with colleagues who prefer the obscure syntax..."_ I dont agree with yajoe nor Cody. Individual developers should _not_ decide the syntax on case-to-case basis, that is simply not how professionals work. The solution is to create a coding style policy for the company.

Comment: _Individual developers should not decide the syntax on case-to-case basis_ It depends on the organization.  Software engineering (which is one place coding styles come from) is an it depends field.  Large organizations that require coordinating across continents: sure there's less room to let individual developers choose.  Small two-man surgical teams: It doesn't really matter what the outcome is so long as the two people agree.

Answer (score 3):

It just not that easy to read, simpler, easier to read and identical approach will be:

```
for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```